# How to print player position on terminal in Sfml?

Tags: c++, sfml

I tried using this code `sf::Vector2f position = game.player_position(); std::cout << "position : " << position << std::endl;` but it didn't work. Here the code in the "player_position()" function
`return sprite.getPosition();`

1. i tried to print player position but it didn't work it gives me an error, the error says "no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits> << sf::Vector2f"

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print a vector and not the values to the standard output. This is not defined. As an easy solution, you can print the x and y values separately.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
    sf::Vector2f v1(16.5f, 24.f);
    std::cout << v1.x << ", " << v1.y << '\n';

    return 1;
}
```

Output is 16.5, 24